# How to add an onclick function to dynamically created divs with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently am dynamically creating divs based on a XML file in one function, using the code below.

```
var ftdImg = "<div class='single-img' id='" + pid + "'><a href='#'><img src='" + projHomeThumbURL + "'/></a><p>" + titleEdit(projName) + "</p><p>" + titleEdit(projCat) + "</p><p>" + projDate + "</p></div>";
var divTag = document.createElement("div");

function createNew(standIn) {
    divTag.innerHTML = standIn;
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(divTag);
}
```

Currently, this code works. I want to add an on click function that replaces the innerHtml of "standin", which is the var ftdImg in my case, with projImgTag:

```
var projImgTag = "<div class ='project-image "+projName+"' id='"+pid+"'><a href='"+projFull+"'><img src='"+projThumb+"/></a></div>";
```

Comment: This style of programming is so deeply flawed that it leaves me speechless. At what point did we decide building the DOM was to be done with a spaghetti bowl of string concatenations? Who is going to maintain this code? If you want to build a DOM use DOM APIs. Or, use a templating language, of which there are dozens if not hundreds. And when did we decide that web programming was about replacing huge DOM blobs with other blobs in on-click handlers? Use CSS classes to select elements to be shown, hidden, or changed. The click handler should be able to do its work with a single class assignment.

Comment: why not use jQuery? it would be so much simpler (Sorry, I can't read your spaghetti code)

Comment: @torazaburo this is a bit harsh of a response, it's probably a beginner. Yes, this is very bad practice, but we can tone the response down. @ starvator While jQuery is a suitable solution, there are vanilla JS ways to do this as well and they're not that difficult

Comment: Hi @starvator, my harshness was not directed at the poster but at the current sorry state of affairs we find ourselves in, where far too many people have been encouraged (largely under the pernicious influence of jQuery) to think of the DOM as a humongous string, to be constructed, concatenated, replaced, regexped, and innerHTML'd.

Comment: Provided that the "spaghetti bowl of strings" is well indented, it is somtimes easier to read and maintain compared to DOM API's. The problem with DOM API's is, apart from its verboseness, the code you type doesn't look anything like the HTML/DOM structure on page. Which makes hunting for code responsible for generating parts of the page more difficult compared to the string concatenation style. Provided it's well formatted of course.

Comment: @torazaburo I think you meant @ chen-asraf

Comment: @slebetman: Point well taken, but the DOM API's can be wrapped in any amount of syntactic sugar, and templating allows writing in HTML structure while handling the `id='"+pid"+:'` with something far more readable like `id={{pid}}`.

Comment: So, this stuff is all based on an XML file, where people will fill out a CSV, which will be converted to an XML when updated. I am building this based on previous files that my job had. I had little to no say as a Jr. Developer on the methodology. And yes, while I understand JavaScript and how it works, I'm still learning the cleaner ways to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *vanilla* js DOM event for handling clicks is `onclick()`:

[**MDN's docs for .onclick()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.onclick = function() {
    /* ... */
};
```

**EDIT**

As well noted by **torazaburo**, the documentation adds:

> You may be inclined to use the EventTarget.addEventListener() method instead, since it is more flexible and part of the DOM Events specification.

Example:

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* ... */
}, false);
```

Comment: Note comment on that page: "You may be inclined to use the `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method instead, since it is more flexible and part of the DOM Events specification."

Comment: @torazaburo - Well noted. Updated.

Comment: I figured out my mistake on my own, but thanks anyways